# Grep run through Applescript ignores arguments

Tags: terminal, grep, applescript

My issue is, I'm trying to quickly search for results in a text file using grep and Terminal. The command

```
grep -F http://myurl.com/whatever urldocument.txt
```

Returns the line with the URL as needed. Frustratingly, using Applescript to get the result with

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "grep -F http://myurl.com/whatever urldocument.txt"
end tell
```

breaks, because for some reason `grep` ignores (some?) commands when run through Applescript, specifically the `-F` part. My question is: Why is this and can I do anything about it?

Comment: **grep -F** works OK for me in Sierra - what system are you running?  Note that **do shell script** shouldn't really be in an application tell statement (it isn't a Terminal command) - does that make a difference in your environment?

Comment: The `do shell script` _command_ is a part of **StandardAdditions** in **AppleScript** and therefore **does not** need to be within a `tell` _block_ and certainly **not** within a **Terminal** `tell` _bock_ as it's not a _command_ in the  **AppleScript Dictionary** for **Terminal**, nor does it even understand the _command_. That said, I tested outside of a  **Terminal** `tell` _bock_ and it works fine; however, I'd place the search string in single quotes. Testing under macOS 10.13.6.